# Is there a way to build or install and run an app running in OSMC along with the normal media center?

Tags: osmc

I'm working on a project involving an rpi running on OSMC in a car. I was wondering if you can have other apps like navit to run beside the media center or/and maybe even connect it to an fm radio module and make an app to browse through the stations since i won't have internet access.(Ability to switch from it and the actual media gui) 
If so please disclose the knowledge I will need to success in my quest.